# PHP exec() command on IIS7

Tags: php, iis-7

I'm trying to start a PHP script as a background task and I'm trying to run the following command:

```
 exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.exe" C:\PHPSites\paul\grocon_inc\en\test.php');
```

but I'm getting lots of error messages in the log:

```
[21-Aug-2015 08:00:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_dba.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

[21-Aug-2015 08:00:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_dbase.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

[21-Aug-2015 08:00:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_fdf.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

[21-Aug-2015 08:00:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_interbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

etc.......

The dll's are there - php scripts run normally. I suspect it's got something to do with permissions but the SYSTEM has full permissions for the dlls. What am I missing?